# Clarinet test command throws error in terminal

Tags: unit-testing, testing, terminal, command, contract

during clarinet contract test if i am trying to  give command like **clarinet.test** it is throwing error like below. Can any one advise me to solve this issue? Please refer below image and advise

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AxbL.png)

Need a solution to my query to test contracts in clarinet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.